# Move changes from sub-branch to new branch off dev

Tags: git, git-branch

I had a branch (`b)` off of dev (`a`) that I was waiting to be merged. In the meantime, I locally branched out `c` from `b` and made some changes. I have not pushed yet.

Now branch `b` has been merged into dev `a`, and `b` deleted off the remote. How can I get my local changes on `c` into a new branch off of `a`, in order to push the changes as a new branch directly off of `a`?

HAVE

```
|
|
|\    |
| \   |
|  | /
|  |/
| /
|/
|
a  b  c
```

WANT

```
|
|  |
|  |
| /
|/
a  d
```

Comment: You can make a branch `d` from `a` and then cherry-pick (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) each commit made in `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @odradek commented, I used `cherry-pick`:

First, use `git log` whilst on branch c:

Copy the hash of the commit I need to cherry pick, and exit by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>

```
git checkout a
git checkout -b d
git cherry-pick {your hash}
```

Fix any conflicts, commit and push.